# Finding voltages in a circuit with no power supply

Tags: circuit-analysis

I´m trying to solve the following circuit

[image]

However I cannot understand how is possible that E2 and E1 have voltage if there is no visible power supply on the circuit. What´s the approach to solve this circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E1, E2, and ground *are* the visible voltage.

You haven't specified what "solve" this circuit means, but you have everything you need to find the voltages at every node and all the currents between the nodes.

Hint: All but one node voltage is explicitly given to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Solve the circuit is find the values of v1,v2 and I. So maybe my problem is an issue with the images. I´m completely new to circuits and from what I´ve seen until now, power supplies are represented with a different image and a white circle like in E1 and E2 just represents a node with no active component on it.

Comment: The way they've drawn it is a little unclear, but the strong implication is that there is a -6V voltage source between E1 and ground. Likewise +18V for E2.

Comment: @Pablo you are correct, those are nodes, but in this diagram the nodes are connected to the indicated voltages.

Comment: And they just drew it weird to try to confuse you....

Comment: @Pablo: You are overthinking this.  The diagram is telling you the voltage at each of the E points explicitly.  Note that since these voltages are not shown with a explicit reference, ground is the implied 0 V reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I´ll just use the voltages as if there are supplies between E1, E2 and ground. I got confused by the absence of the supply drawing. Thanks again.